# Do I need to retain access to this pipe in my basement when building a shower?

Tags: basement, radon

I have a PVC pipe probably 4 in coming from basement floor and going to roof.

I am wondering if I need access for this. I am putting a bathroom and current plan was to put tiles shower on that wall. And I am wondering if I should change if I need access.

Also is it a working radon system or do I need to add fan or something later. I don’t see any fan. Any advice will be very helpful.
[image]

Thanks Ecnerwal. Where do people typically add fan assuming it is passive radon? I saw some where a fan in attic. I do have access to attic.

I didn’t quite get usefulness of access. Can you be kind enough to provide more details?

This is my attic where I think that pipe is going.

[image]

I do also see couple of fans in back. Is any of those seem like radon fan? And do I still need access of it is a radon fan.

[image]

Comment: The wall vents appear to be for HVAC and/or power-vented water heater.

Comment: I just love to observe that some people will bury a toilet tank, that will inevitably fail within 3 years, inside a beautiful new bathroom wall with no thought to access, whereas here we have someone who wants to make sure he can provide appropriate TLC to a plastic pipe at all points in the future.   There should be a LoveTheNextOwner badge for you.

Comment: And to answer your question of where to put a radon fan: around here (iowa), you have to have it in the attic or outside. NOT in the basement. The theory is if something goes wrong, you don't want it blowing radon-air in to your basement. Above the living space our outside is fine.

Comment: This is being closed because you're asking 2 separate questions: 1) What's this pipe, and 2) Is it a radon system/where are the fans.

Comment: wow. This seems little excessive to close this becasuse of 2 different question. But I respect the policy. Anyway, I am pretty sure now it is Radon pipe and i can add fan in attic in future if needed. Thank you @jay613 for observing my obsession to details. I have decided to move shower anyway to the other side as it is not a big deal. All set on this. Thanks to all who replied.

Answer (score 2):

To address the question about adding a fan to a passive Radon system:

A passive Radon mitigation system is just that - passive.  The concentration of Radon in the area is not enough to justify a fan constantly pulling vacuum under the slab.

The passive system gives the Radon gas a "path of least resistance" so-to-speak, so that it can safely bypass your indoor air and dissipate to the atmosphere.  Running a fan in such a system would only waste energy and potentially affect the operation of your HVAC system if a crack were to develop in the future, allowing the fan to pull air from the conditioned space.

Don't worry about it - cover the pipe.  If the builder had finished the basement, you wouldn't even know it was there anyway.

Comment: A test to verify that levels **are** safe is advisable. But if that's the case, then adding a fan is certainly a waste of money and energy (more money.)

Answer (score 1):

It *may* be a plumbing vent.

It *may* be a **passive** radon vent. In the case of a radon test indicating a problematic level of radon, a passive vent can be converted to an **active** one by adding a radon fan, **if** that's what this pipe is. Normally there would be a manometer attached down here at that time to indicate suction, and an access panel would therefore be wise at this time. Or, y'know, the $15 or so radon test indicating that you don't need a fan, *if* that's what it is...it *should* have been labeled, but that's not an uncommon oversight for one left passive, unfortunately.

For a passive vent, there is no fan. If converting to an active vent, the fan is normally placed as high on the pipe as practical, but fan life is generally longer if it's not actually outside, so in the attic would be typical for this install. The fans claim to be weatherproof, but "real people experience" is that they do last longer if protected. Putting it above the living space means any leaks will be inward, not outward, in the living space. You definitely need access to the fan location, as they do expire and require replacement.

The manometer to indicate that pressure in the pipe is lower than pressure in the basement is the primary reason you want the pipe to have an access in the basement. That shows that the fan is working as it should, IF you need and have a fan at all. You could preconfigure one to a spot outside the shower area, and not need to access it *so long as nothing breaks.* **I** would prefer having a small access panel where the manometer connection is made, rather than potentially having to break tiles in the case of a tubing failure.

A different option that requires no pipe access would be manometers into the floor away from the pipe, which are sometimes used. Those show the pressure differential from the basement to the underfloor venting area, and are thus somewhat better, even - but less commonly seen than one on the pipe as it enters the floor.

You don't (ever) need a fan on this, unless you have a test showing that radon levels are elevated.

Comment: An access in a shower wall is a recipe for headaches. Why couldn't a manometer be installed in the attic, below a fan? Theoretically, pressure is the same everywhere in the system.

Comment: Theory and practice are the same in theory, but different in practice. A manometer in the attic doesn't show the effect in the basement of the fuel-burning appliance vents, exhaust vents, and other things that may affect the pressure inside the building envelope - and also does not show the pressure differential at the entrance to the floor.

Answer (score 1):

Any drain/vent pipe in a modern home will have a cleanout near the floor. This doesn't, so we can reasonably assume that it's a Radon mitigation circuit.

If that's the case I wouldn't consider it important to retain access. Should you wish to add a fan later (to create an *active* system), it can go in the attic.